# How to get JSON data from a file into an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, json

This is my folder structure

project
-->javascript-->classroom-->classroom-->classdetail-->controller-->classcontrol.js
 directive-->classdetailDirective.js(directive and controller are at the same level, ie after the classdetail file)

-->languages-->classroom-->classroomdata.json

-->templates-->classroom-->classroom-->classdetail-->classdetail.html
  directives--classdetailDirective.html (classdetail folder opens classdetail.html and directives folder which in turn gives access to classdetailDirective.html)

The json file has the data {"classSize" : "60"}

This is how the classdetailDirective.js file looks like

```
app.directive('classDetail', function(){  
return{  
restrict : 'E',  
scope : {isPresent: '='  
},  
templateUrl : 'templates/classroom/classroom/classdetail/directives/classdetailDirective.html'  
}  
});
```

The controller is not doing anything at the moment. Any form of modification will do.

In the classdetailDirective.html, I want to show the classSize information in the form of a tooltip.

```
<div title="{{classSize}}"></div>
```

I tried using $http.get but it didn't work. I have no clue how to get this done. Please help. I again, apologize for the way I wrote this question. This is the first time.

Comment: normally to access json files we just use $http.get. Can you show us how you used it?

Comment: I used it in the following way
$http.get("languages/classroom/classroom.json").then(function(response){
   $scope.showToolTip = response.classSize;
)};

Comment: there is no need to use http to get static json file that's part of your project, for this kind of data normal import should be fine, check answer for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately the classroomdata.json file has to be left alone. It is a huge file but I only need the classSize data from that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use the http method to fetch the data, like:

```
app.directive('classDetail', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("relative-path-to-your-json-file")
       .then(function (response) {$scope.data = response.data;});
});
```

Comment: I was getting the relative path wrong. Your solution gave me an idea how to solve this. I was just getting started with UI development. Thanks and sorry for the very late reply

Answer (score 0):

Hi given your project structure I'd suggest to include json-loader if you use webpack in your project, or another solution is to put json in export function, change:

/languages/classroom/classroomdata.json

to

/languages/classroom/classroomdata.js

**classroomdata.js**

```
export default ()=> {
  // return your json here
  return {"classSize" : "60"}; 
}
```

then inside your directive on top do(path might not be exact so try to work it out):

```
import classroomData from '../../../../../languages/classroom/classroomdata.js';
```

now just use classroomData variable in directive that will have your json

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment on how you are using $http.get

you should be able to get the data in your json by using response.data based on your code you are using it like this

```
response.classSize
```

try this

```
 $http.get("languages/classroom/classroom.json").then(functio‌​n(response){ 
 $scope.showToolTip = response.data.classSize; 
 )};
```